# Does it makes sense to batch update within a transaction in Flutter with Firebase?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My goal is to make a transaction to delete a user and all his documents (users and ads collections).

When I delete a user, I'd like to update his ads with a "deleted":true in the ads collection.

So I wrote this code as follows:

```dart
  /// Marks user as deleted
  Future<void> storeMarkAsDeleted() async {
    final fs = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    final writeBatch = fs.batch();

    // = Open a transaction to perform both operations
    return fs.runTransaction((t) async {
      final user = await t.get(fs.collection(collectionName).doc(id));

      /// Reads the ad document
      final ads = await fs
          .collection(collectionName)
          .where("ownerId", isEqualTo: id)
          .get();

      // Mark user as deleted
      t.update(user.reference, {
        "deleted": true,
      });

      // Update all docs
      for (final doc in ads.docs) {
     
        writeBatch.update(doc.reference, {
          "clearedForSale": false,
          "deleted": true,
        });
      }
      // unless commit is called, nothing happens.
      writeBatch.commit();
    });
  }
```

But I am not sure if this is the right way to do?

Comment: As Doug answered below: the batch write you have is **not** part of the transaction. So unless you want the batch write to potentially execute multiple times, this is probably not the right approach.

Comment: My answer to your other linked question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/77426040/3371862) proposes an approach based on a Cloud Function, since you can execute a Query in Transactions ran in a Cloud Function (which you cannot do for Transactions ran in a front-end).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is definitely not "right". You should be aware that a transaction handler can run multiple times (rolling back any changes before a re-run) in order to deal with contention on the transacted documents.  Running a batch (or any other non-transaction queries) within a transaction means they might happen multiple times, resulting in more document being read or written than you intended.

Inside a transaction, you should only use the transaction object to read and write documents.

I suggest reviewing the [documentation for transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#transactions) in order to understand how they behave.

Comment: Gotcha but how should I make sure that the user is deleted as long as his documents in atomically way?

Comment: That sounds like a different question than the one you already have here.  Please post it separately. But I can tell you that Firestore transactions only work with documents in Firestore and nothing else.